# How to download whole ECW or JPG tiles from web viewer?

Tags: tiles, erdas-imagine, ecw

I've found an online server which has some aerial tiles I'd like to save at maximal resolution for offline use, I'd even be happy with just the whole JPG picture to be later georeferenced again by myself.

I did try to test the source URL and found it's probably using an ERDAS ecw server setup and JPG tiles (also probably found the remote ECW directory but seemingly gives an access error message), however being no more experienced than reading some HTML, I don't know how I'd download the whole image at maximum zoom.

Upon looking potentially similar discussions I came across a software called taho, however I think it may not apply to my case.

Could you help me?

Here is the webpage viewer URL: //fotogrammi.regione.abruzzo.it/sampleiws/fotogrammi.asp?VOLO=VIGM54&&LOTTO=1&&STR_=48&&FOTO=1686

and here a sample tile URL //fotogrammi.regione.abruzzo.it/ecwp/ImageX.dll?image?cache=true&transparent=true&type=jpg&l=0&tx=9&ty=9&ts=256&fill=FFFFFF&quality=60&layers=/VIGM54/1/48/1686.ecw&srs=EPSG:RAW

which, also considering the peculiar "error" page (shows a local "C:\Program Files\ERDAS\Image Web Server" remote directory line) that loads up, led me to think that the ecw is stored at .../ecwp/VIGM54/1/48/1686.ecw

Comment: did you find a workaround to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

## Dezoomify

You can use [dezoomify](https://github.com/lovasoa/dezoomify#dezoomify) to download the full image.

### Instructions

1. Take the original tile URL. In your case:

```
http://fotogrammi.regione.abruzzo.it/ecwp/ImageX.dll?image?cache=true&transparent=true&type=jpg&l=0&tx=9&ty=9&ts=256&fill=FFFFFF&quality=60&layers=/VIGM54/1/48/1686.ecw&srs=EPSG:RAW
```

2. Replace the values after `tx=` and `ty=` by `{{X}}` and `{{Y}}` respectively. Optionally, for a faster download, replace the value after `ts=` by `2000`. In your case, this gives:

```
http://fotogrammi.regione.abruzzo.it/ecwp/ImageX.dll?image?cache=true&transparent=true&type=jpg&l=0&tx={{X}}&ty={{Y}}&ts=2000&fill=FFFFFF&quality=60&layers=/VIGM54/1/48/1686.ecw&srs=EPSG:RAW
```

3. Paste the result into the text field on [dezoomify](https://ophir.alwaysdata.net/dezoomify).
4. Validate.
5. The image should now download, tile by tile. When it is done, right-click on it and choose *Save As*.

Here is [a discussion](https://github.com/lovasoa/dezoomify/issues/207) about using dezoomify to download images from an ECW web viewer.

#### Result

[image: downloaded high-resolution photograph]
(the image quality was reduced by imgur. You can follow the procedure to get the original full quality photograph)